# How to retry only requests that resulted in 500 and did it below given time threshold?

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java, reactive-programming

**Tech stack**: `rx-java` 1.1.x, `retrofit` 1.9.x, `spring` 4.3.x.

**A bit of context:**
I'm pretty new to rx-java. My service A has an API endpoint that makes a search call to service B that is frequently used, and fails a bit too often then it should. Some of the errors are pretty clear timeouts from other different services deep down, that took >30s, but quite a lot of them are pretty quick ones, around <1s.

**What exactly I'm trying to do:**
Retry only the calls that fail under given threshold (let's say <1s), ideally the ones returning 5xx HTTP code responses.

**Ideas that came to my mind, but do not solve the problem:**
Regular `Observable.timeout()` seems of no use, because for now I don't want to touch (interrupt) calls that are taking longer. I only want to retry those that came back as failed (`5XX` response), not interrupt the longer ones.
`retry()` seems of no use, because I don't want to simply retry every failed call.
`retryWhen()` could be of use, but I am not sure how can I extract the HTTP from a Throwable and what exactly should I measure in the Observable call.

**Code:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(...)
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public DeferredResult<MyJsonWrapper> fetchSomething() {
    MySearchRequest searchRequest, 
    BindingResult bindingResult, 
    HttpServletRequest request) {

    return new MyDeferredResult(
        serviceB.searchSomething(...)
        .doOnNext( result -> /* log size of search */ ));
    }
```

`serviceB.searchSomething(...)` also returns `Observable<MyJsonWrapper>`

What is MyDeferredResult:

```
class MyDeferredResult<T> extends DeferredResult<T> {

    public MyDeferredResult(Observable<T> observable) {

        onTimeout(this::handleTimeout);
        ConnectableObservable<T> publication = observable.publish();
        publication.subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError, this::onCompleted);
        publication.connect(subscription -> this.subscription = subscription);
    }

    (...)
    private void handleTimeout() {
        setErrorResult(new MyTimeoutException( /* some info about request */ ));
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

How can I retry only the requests that failed under 1s that are 5xx HTTP responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to implement a working solution. To measure the Observable's time I chose Spring's `StopWatch`, started counting in `doOnSubscribe()` and stopped in `doOnTerminate()`.

I create the StopWatch and pass it to my custom retry function used in `retryWhen()`, and only when the code goes to the `retryWhen()` block I check if the time was under my given threshold.

How my call looks like now:

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
int executionTimeThresholdMillis = 1000; // 1 second

return new MyDeferredResult(
    serviceB.searchSomething(...)
    .doOnSubscribe(stopWatch::start)
    .doOnTerminate(stopWatch::stop)
    .retryWhen(
        return RetryGivenHttpResponsesUnderThreshold.builder()
            .maxRetries(MAX_RETRIES)
            .httpResponsesToRetry(List.of(HTTP_CODE_TO_FAIL))
            .observableExecutionTime(stopWatch)
            .executionTimeThresholdMillis(executionTimeThresholdMillis)
            .build())
    .doOnNext( result -> /* log size of search */ ));
}
```

Now, the example of how could you implement the retry function. I want both checking the HTTP response and elapsed time, so the code is only somehow configurable. I hope someone else will also use it and then change it accordingly to one's needs:

```
public class RetryGivenHttpResponsesUnderThreshold implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {


private final int maxRetries;
private final Collection<Integer> httpResponsesToRetry;
private int retryCount;

private final boolean isMeasurable;
private final long maxObservableExecutionTimeMilis;
private final StopWatch stopWatch;

(...) 
// constructors, builders, validations...

@Override
public Observable<?> call(final Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
    return attempts
            .flatMap(throwable -> {
                boolean needsRetry = false;
                if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                    if (httpResponsesToRetry.contains(((HttpException) throwable).code())) {

                        // !IMPORTANT! in my case I want to get getLastTaskTimeMillis(), and NOT getTotalTimeMillis()
                        // because the timer will be stopped on every error that will trigger retry
                        final long observableExecutionTimeMilis = stopWatch.getLastTaskTimeMillis();

                        if (isMeasurable) {
                            needsRetry = observableExecutionTimeMilis <= maxObservableExecutionTimeMilis;
                        } else  {
                            needsRetry = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (needsRetry && retryCount < maxRetries) {
                    retryCount++;
                    // Simply retry.
                    return Observable.just(null);
                }

                // Just pass the error along.
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A very simple retry example when the response status is **500**. You can include the multiple conditions along with the **status code(500)** and where it throw *IOException* so that the *retry feature* is start to execute. Assume the true value for time thresold is **THRESOLD**

```
public void retriesFor500HttpResponse() throws Exception {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
          .addInterceptorLast(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
              @Override
              public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                  if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 500 && THRESOLD) {
                      throw new IOException("Retry it");
                  }
              }
          })
          .build()) {

            executeFor500Status(httpClient, STATUS_500_URL);
        }
    }

    private void executeFor500Status(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, String url) throws IOException {

        //....
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to reply, but unfortunately this doesn't answer my question.
I need to somehow measure a call that returns Observable and invoke `retryWhen()` and the function in the retryWhen() needs to have the information how long actually did the call took.
Your answer doesn't provide a solution for that. It focuses only on the error code, not measuring the time and passing it. Anyway, thank you for the effort!